An error occurred while submitting the modal, something went wrong
I want to ask why, when I run the bot and press submit in the modal, I get the error "something went wrong". Is it possible that I'm using it incorrectly?
I want to create a confession feature that automatically creates a new thread in a Discord forum when a button is pressed, allowing users to choose between submitting anonymously or displaying their nickname.
How it works:

The bot creates a new post (to use the button functionality).
Users can choose one of two options for anonymity.
When the option button is pressed, a form will appear for entering the content information.
When 'submit' is pressed, the bot will automatically create a new thread with the title 'Confession' followed by a sequential number and the content entered by the user.

However, at the submit step, I am unable to execute the command.
This is my code :
require('dotenv').config();
const { Client, GatewayIntentBits, Events, ActionRowBuilder, ButtonBuilder, ButtonStyle, ModalBuilder, TextInputBuilder, TextInputStyle, ChannelType } = require('discord.js');

const client = new Client({
    intents: [
        GatewayIntentBits.Guilds,
        GatewayIntentBits.GuildMessages,
        GatewayIntentBits.MessageContent,
    ],
});

// ID của kênh forum
const forumChannelId = '1294368354764853358';
let confessionCount = 0;

client.once('ready', () => {
    console.log('Bot đã hoạt động!');
});

// Lắng nghe tin nhắn để tạo bài viết hướng dẫn
client.on('messageCreate', async (message) => {
    if (message.content === '!post') {
        const channel = await client.channels.fetch(forumChannelId);
        
        if (channel && channel.type === ChannelType.GuildForum) {
            const row = new ActionRowBuilder()
                .addComponents(
                    new ButtonBuilder().setCustomId('confess_anonymous').setLabel('Confession Ẩn Danh').setStyle(ButtonStyle.Success),
                    new ButtonBuilder().setCustomId('confess_with_nickname').setLabel('Confession Hiện Nickname').setStyle(ButtonStyle.Success)
                );

            await channel.threads.create({
                name: 'Hướng dẫn gửi confession',
                autoArchiveDuration: 60,
                reason: 'Tạo bài post mới hướng dẫn gửi confession',
                message: {
                    content: 'Chọn 1 trong 2 nút dưới để gửi confession nha.\nBot sẽ gửi tin nhắn riêng thông báo cho bạn khi confession được duyệt.',
                    components: [row],
                },
            });

            console.log('Bài viết hướng dẫn đã được tạo.');
        } else {
            console.error('Kênh không phải là forum.');
        }
    }
});

// Lắng nghe phản hồi từ nút và hiển thị modal
client.on(Events.InteractionCreate, async (interaction) => {
    if (interaction.isButton()) {
        const modal = new ModalBuilder()
            .setCustomId('confession_modal')
            .setTitle(interaction.customId === 'confess_anonymous' ? 'Confession Ẩn Danh' : 'Confession Hiện Nickname')
            .addComponents(
                new ActionRowBuilder().addComponents(
                    new TextInputBuilder()
                        .setCustomId('confession_input')
                        .setLabel('Nhập nội dung confession')
                        .setStyle(TextInputStyle.Paragraph)
                )
            );

        await interaction.showModal(modal);
        console.log('Modal displayed successfully');
    }
});

// Lắng nghe phản hồi từ modal
client.on(Events.ModalSubmit, async (modalInteraction) => {
    if (modalInteraction.isModalSubmit()) {
        const confession = modalInteraction.fields.getTextInputValue('confession_input');
        const channel = await client.channels.fetch(forumChannelId);

        if (channel && channel.type === ChannelType.GuildForum) {
            confessionCount++;
            const confessionTitle = `Confession ${confessionCount}`;

            try {
                await channel.threads.create({
                    name: confessionTitle,
                    autoArchiveDuration: 60,
                    reason: 'Tạo bài post mới cho confession',
                    message: {
                        content: confession,
                    },
                });

                console.log('Post created successfully');
                await modalInteraction.reply({ content: 'Confession của bạn đã được ghi nhận!', ephemeral: true });
            } catch (error) {
                console.error('Error creating post:', error);
                await modalInteraction.reply({ content: 'Đã xảy ra lỗi khi tạo bài viết. Vui lòng thử lại.', ephemeral: true });
            }
        } else {
            console.error('Kênh không phải là forum hoặc không tồn tại.');
            await modalInteraction.reply({ content: 'Kênh không phải là forum hoặc không tồn tại.', ephemeral: true });
        }
    }
});

// Đăng nhập vào bot Discord
client.login(process.env.YOUR_DISCORD_TOKEN);

Im using chatgpt to create it and edit, hope someone can help
I have tried various commands to find errors in the Linux console log, but the results do not show anything additional; it just repeats the part
console.log('Modal displayed successfully');


Listening to Events.ModalSubmit isn't the right thing to do in your case, when a modal is submitted the Events.InteractionCreate event is called.
You have to modify your code to the following:
// Code before

client.on(Events.InteractionCreate, async (interaction) => {
    if (interaction.isButton()) {
        const modal = new ModalBuilder()
            .setCustomId('confession_modal')
            .setTitle(interaction.customId === 'confess_anonymous' ? 'Confession Ẩn Danh' : 'Confession Hiện Nickname')
            .addComponents(
                new ActionRowBuilder().addComponents(
                    new TextInputBuilder()
                        .setCustomId('confession_input')
                        .setLabel('Nhập nội dung confession')
                        .setStyle(TextInputStyle.Paragraph)
                )
            );

        await interaction.showModal(modal);
        console.log('Modal displayed successfully');
    } else if (interaction.isModalSubmit()) {
        const confession = interaction.fields.getTextInputValue('confession_input');
        const channel = await client.channels.fetch(forumChannelId);

        if (channel && channel.type === ChannelType.GuildForum) {
            confessionCount++;
            const confessionTitle = `Confession ${confessionCount}`;

            try {
                await channel.threads.create({
                    name: confessionTitle,
                    autoArchiveDuration: 60,
                    reason: 'Tạo bài post mới cho confession',
                    message: {
                        content: confession,
                    },
                });

                console.log('Post created successfully');
                await interaction.reply({ content: 'Confession của bạn đã được ghi nhận!', ephemeral: true });
            } catch (error) {
                console.error('Error creating post:', error);
                await interaction.reply({ content: 'Đã xảy ra lỗi khi tạo bài viết. Vui lòng thử lại.', ephemeral: true });
            }
        } else {
            console.error('Kênh không phải là forum hoặc không tồn tại.');
            await interaction.reply({ content: 'Kênh không phải là forum hoặc không tồn tại.', ephemeral: true });
        }
    }
});

// Code after

It should fix your issue!
Be aware of ChatGPT/AI generated code, it often leads to unexpected issues and it is advised to code by yourself :)
